# Python shows record's old value after restart

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, cherrypy, updating

I have an script to show database records using MySQLdb and cherrypy as table. My problem is when I update values from outside of the script it updates the old values and I need to restart it to show new values.

my DB class in mod/db.py:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb


class DB:
    con = None

    def __init__(self):
        if DB.con is None:
            DB.connect()

    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        DB.con = mdb.connect('myhost', 'myuser', 'mypass', 'mydb')

    @staticmethod
    def _query(q, values, commit):
        cur = DB.con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute(q, values)
        if commit:
            DB.con.commit()
            return cur.rowcount
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    @staticmethod
    def query(q, values, commit=False):
        try:
            return DB._query(q, values, commit)
        except mdb.OperationalError:
            DB.connect()
            return DB._query(q, values, commit)
```

and this is how I use it:

```
from mod import db
def get_data(username):
    data = []
    for elm in db.DB.query("select name, value from data user=%s", (username,)):
        data.append(elm)
    return data
```

get_data works fine but when script is running and I change records using mysql

```
mysql> update data set value=(rand() * 21);
Query OK, 51 rows affected (0.23 sec)
Rows matched: 51  Changed: 51  Warnings: 0
```

and then call get_data it returns old values.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25991345/2072035). Basically PEP-249 is [blatantly wrong](https://mysqlsimplequerybuilder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/design.html#autocommit) about default disabled autocommit in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks adding DB.con.autocommit(True) solved the problem.